# Best way to extract last segment of URI in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, uri, string-parsing

Given URI strings like:

```
http://www.somesite.com/abc
http://www.somesite.com/alpha/beta/abc
http://www.somesite.com/alpha/abc
```

What's the most elegant way in Ruby to grab the `abc` at the end of these URIs?

Comment: @oldergod: `http://example.com/where?is=pancakes/house%3F`.

Comment: @muistooshort how would you do it? taking everything from the last `/` before the first `?`?

Comment: @oldergod: yeah, see Gumbo's answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I would use a proper URI parser like the one of the [URI module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) to get the path from the URI. Then split it at `/` and get the last part of it:

```
require 'uri'

URI(uri).path.split('/').last
```

Comment: @oldergod So what do you get instead?

Comment: @muistooshort You can use `path.chomp('/')` to remove them before splitting.

Answer (score 15):

```
uri.split('/')[-1]
```

or

```
uri.split('/').last
```

Answer (score 7):

While all the usages of `split` suggested in the answers here are legit, in my opinion [@matsko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345602/best-way-to-extract-last-segment-of-uri-in-ruby#answer-12345659) is the one with the clearer code to read:

```
last = File.basename(url)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try these:

```
if url =~ /\/(.+?)$/
  last = $1
end
```

Or

```
last = File.basename(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Terminal command line:

```
ruby -ruri -e "print File.basename(URI.parse('$URI').path)"
```

from inside your .rb source:

```
require 'uri'
theURI = 'http://user:pass@example.com/foo/bar/baz/?lala=foo'
uriPathTail = File.basename(URI.parse(theURI).path) # => baz
```

it works well with whatever legal theURI you had.

If you don't use URI.parse(), any parameter to the url will be wrongly taken as the last segment of the URI.

Answer (score 2):

If the value is any orbitary string + URI, then the below solution should work.

First, extract URI from the string:

```
uri_string = URI.extract("Test 123 http://www.somesite.com/abc")
```

Above command returns an array

Then extract the last part of the URI using

```
uri_string[0].split('/').last
```

prerequisite: require "uri" needs to be added to the ruby script